# How do I properly create a loop for a user who inputted a date incorrectly?

Tags: java, loops, date, parsing, time

So, I just recently learned how to create a loop that can reiterate a particular line of code if certain criteria aren't met. After repetitive practice, I've successfully been able to use the loop with many different programs, but I've run into an issue that I can't resolve when it comes to a user inputting the wrong format for a date. Here's the code that is giving me problems:

loop:

```
while(true) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Date: ");

    date1 = scanner.next();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date date2=null;
    try {

        date2 = dateFormat.parse(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("The date you've entered is: " + date2);
    break loop;
}
```

When I test what happens if I enter the wrong date (say for instance I simply input the number 3) it continues to the next lines of code whilst telling me that the inputted date could not be parsed because the format was wrong. Why isn't it looping? This is the error it gives me verbatim:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "3"

The date you've entered is: null

Customer 1 profile:
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Creations.Shop.main(Shop.java:82)
```

Comment: You should either move the `System.out.println()` into the `try` block, or add a `continue;` inside the `catch` block. What happens now is that the codes continue to run after you have caught the exception, which would eventually break the loop.

Comment: the break statement stops the loop. Just remove the `break loop;`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please help us read your code: indent it properly. Your IDE can do that for you.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you catch the ParseException due to code failure in the try block, the code inside that catch block will execute. So, currently it is just printing the stack trace (error message) with the `e.printStackTrace();` statement. Instead of that, you need a continue statement there like so,

```
catch (ParseException e) {
   continue; // this skips the next code lines till the end of the loop
}
```

Also, you don't need to generate a Scanner object every-time in the loop. You can initialize it once outside the while loop and use it inside the loop later.